# Xcode Auto-Layout Issue for smaller screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout

All screen sizes display the app as expected except 3.5 Inches, that is always off by a long shot. What can I do to prevent this?

[image]

Comment: Can u show us constraints for that under 2 0% button

Comment: We should know all the constraints especially in vertically.

Comment: have you tried putting the views into a UIStackView?  Vertical UIStackView might do the trick

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder, you'll want to set constraints for compact screen sizes. At the bottom, you'll see this:

[image]

Change that to Compact Height x Compact width and set constraints for that screen size.

Comment: It says those settings are only for landscape, is that true?